# Java MariaDB no suitable driver found

Tags: java, mariadb, sqlexception, connector

I'm trying to connect my Java app to MariaDB database. MariaDB is properly installed and it can be used with DBeaver without any issue. However, my Java app cannot connect to the database. Here is how my project looks like. I have imported the mariaDB connector to the project properly. Am I doing something wrong? I can't figure out what could be the problem. Please, can anyone can help regarding this issue?

Specs:
Mac
IDE Eclipse
JDK17
MariaDB
v11.1.2
MariaDB connector 3.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwyrs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLvOe.png)

I use to work with Java19, so I downgraded to 17 but the error is the same. I have tried many restart the IDE after importing the MariaDB connector jar file. I have followed many tutorials but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
You need to add the MariaDB dependency, but you've given no details of what type of project you've got so it's hard to day how to do that

Answer (score 1):

the problem is propably the string at line 14, try this .

```
            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/your_database_name";
            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";
    
          try {
                Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    
                // Create a database connection
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, 
   password);
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}catch (SQLException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think this is the legacy way to load the driver : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that the jdbc driver jar is in fact on the class path. One trick you can use is to simply [print out the classpath at the start of program execution.](https://java2blog.com/print-classpath-java/) If it *is* on your classpath, I'd be very surprised. If it is *not*, then you now have a line of investigation: How do you ensure that the driver jar is on your classpath when running within Eclipse?

Comment: The driver was loaded properly, however, it was the wrong file. But thank you very much for this command, it's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I was using the wrong file : mariadb-java-client-3.2.0-sources.jar I use this instead : mariadb-java-client-3.2.0.jar It's working now